# Disable menu item containing children

Tags: delphi, vcl

How to disable a menu item which is the root of a submenu?

The code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PopupActionBar1: TPopupActionBar;
    bbb: TMenuItem;
    aaa: TMenuItem;
    a111: TMenuItem;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
    
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  aaa.Enabled := False;
  a111.Enabled := False;
  bbb.Enabled := False;
end;

end.
```

The result (the item `aaa` is neither grayed nor actually disabled):

[image]

Comment: You can check [Parent](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.Parent) to get reference to parent menu item so you can do with it what you need.

Comment: I meant that the menu item is not disabled though it should have been

Comment: Works for me as expected using Delphi 7 [on Windows 7 with styles/themes disabled](https://abload.de/img/disabled8wenf.png). Wanna tell us your Delphi version and/or try to disable themes?

Comment: @AmigoJack: Yes, this certainly works for a `TPopupMenu`. However, the OP is using a (strange thing called) `TPopupActionBar`.

Comment: Yes true, I changed TPopupMenu  to TPopupActionBar some 10 years ago when found that TPopupMenu didnt work properly with Styles, Large fonts etc. Maybe its time to get back to origins?

Comment: I think you found a bug in this component. A workaround could be to Assign an empty action and disable the assigned action.

Comment: @Molochnik: Yes. Use a standard `TPopupMenu`.

Comment: @Leonard there is not actions, just an empty menu item. Now I am goint to check TPopupMenu

Comment: Yes TPopupMenu works perfect, the discussion can be closed, thamks to all who answered